# GWT Code splitting. Splited file not load intime

Tags: gwt, split

I have a problem. In large GWT(2.4)-app i desided used gwt-code-splitting. GWT-compiller cropped app for a small js-parts.

but, whean I want to load some module

```
final Module form = ModuleFactory.getInstance().getModule(modumesName);
```

/***/

```
private Module module = null;

public Module getModule(String moduleName){
 if (moduleName.equals("M1")) {
 GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {      
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            module = GWT.create(M1.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
            Window.alert("not load M1");
        }
    });
  }
return module;
}
```

M1 extend Module

When I call creating widget M1 at first time, I got a js error

"Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses "

but, on other time, im got my module M1. In development tools I saw, that split part loaded.

```
public class CreateModuleWidget extends Composite{
     private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
     interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, CreateModuleWidget> {}

     public CreateModuleWidget() {
           /*initparams**/ 
     }

     @UiHandler("createButt")
     void onCreateClick(ClickEvent event) {
          String modumesName = "M1";
          final WidgetDialog dialog = new WidgetDialog(moduleName, true);
          final Module form = ModuleFactory.getInstance().getModule(modumesName);
          dialog.setDialogWidget(form);
          dialog.show();
     }
}

public class ModuleFactory{
    private Module form = null;

private static ModuleFactory instance = null;

public static ModuleFactory getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new ModuleFactory();
    }
    return instance;
}
    public Module getModule(String moduleName){
        if (moduleName.equals("M1")) {
           GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {        
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            module = GWT.create(M1.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
            Window.alert("not load M1");
        }
    });
          }
    return module;
   }
 }
```

Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses BDC16B1A93B4190A8C1DD66EEF9838B8.cache.html:1435
(anonymous function)

Comment: Please  paste the full stacktrace.

Comment: thank! Im added full code

Comment: in development mode (with gwt browser plugin) all worked fine. but, when I'm compile projet and deploy on a appserver, my app work wrong

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know, it's called `runAsync` for a reason: it's **a**-synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do this as part of MVC.

Controller checks if the module it needs is null, if so it loads it and then proceeds to the view after obtaining the needed code.

```
Module module;



   if (module==null){

          //You could display a waiting message in a dialog

          GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {  
           ...
          　　public void onSuccess() {
                　　module = GWT.create(M1.class);
                　　showXYZView();
           　　}
　　　　　});

    }else{
          showXYZView();
    }
```